# LibGDX Sprite + Box2D CircleShape: Positioning while taking into account origin

Tags: java, libgdx, position, box2d

My problem is, that my Box2D Body has another position than the LibGDX Sprite I want to render for that body. In my render-loop, for each body, I'm setting the position of it's sprite to the one of the body, and then rendering it. 
When creating a Box2D Shape other than a circle, Box2D does not move it from it's origin, and neither does the LibGDX-sprite. If I now move or set the position of the body, my sprite will always follow it. But, unfortunately, this is not possible with CircleShapes: Since LibGDX's Sprite#setPosition does not take into account the origin of the sprite (Which is only used for scaling and rotating), the sprite is set by it's lowerleft corner. So here is the problem: The Box2D CircleShape is moved by taking into account the origin! So my sprite always starts in the origin of the shape. Does anyone know how to fix that? And, ultimately, I'd want to *always* move *both* while taking into account the origin. How do I do that?

Comment: You need to use an offset. As you said the `draw()` methods of libgdx do use the lower, left corner, while `Box2D` `Body`s usually use their center. Therefore you need to move the `Sprite` to the left and down by half of it's width and height.

Comment: @Springrbua Thanks for the answer! The problem is, that not all Box2D Bodies use  their center - For example, custom shapes, or rectangles, use the lowerleft corner too. I'd like too draw everything from the center :/

Comment: It may work, if you use `getWorldCenter()` instead of `getPosition()`. This method returns the center of mass of this body, in world coordinates. In many cases the center of mass is just the `Body`s center and the offset for the `Sprite` is `-Body.width/2` and `-Body.height/2`. In some cases this won't work...

Answer (score 2):

Box2d body origin is never changed. The Circle and Box shape's origin is middle and the polygon shape's origin is the bottom left corner.
The only way to fix it, you change the sprite origin to middle that is `Sprite.setOriginCenter();`.

If body is a circle or box shape, the sprite position set like as 
 `sprite.setPosition(body.getPosition().x - sprite.getWidth()/2, body.getPosition().y - sprite.getHeight()/2);`.
If body is a polygon shape the code should be like as 
`sprite.setPosition(body.getPosition().x, body.getPosition().y);`.